# Analysing proportion land coverage per raster cell from polygon layers

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I want to analyse the proportion of land use coverage of 12 different land use categories per area. The idea is to create a table as listed below, with the study area I have divided in cells, which either have a presence (1) or absence (0) of little owls. In this way I create a binary model which I can use for analysis with a GLM.I have a polygon layer that contains all values 0 (all absence values) and one for all values 1 (all presence values).

How can I extract the information I need from the data I have? Should I convert the polygon layers to raster layers for example? In that way I could maybe analyse the proportion of land use per cell using *zonal histogram* for example? Any other ideas?

Absence layer:
[image]

Presence layer:
[image]

And this is a short example of what I want the output to look like:
[image]

Comment: Those are not rasters. Are you saying you also have a raster layer? Try [statistics by categories](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#qgisstatisticsbycategories)

Comment: No I thought I needed to turn these into raster layers in order to do what I want to do, because I want to have statistics per cell instead of per categories. So I think statistics by categories is not what I need.